# How do I add a description to the node title form field?

Tags: 7, nodes

This might sound stupid, but I can't find a way to do it. I need to add a description to the node title, just like I add a description to other fields. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, add a description attribute to the node form element array:

```
 //Add a title field description
  $form['title']['#description'] = t('Enter your awesome title field details.');
```

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8 is pretty similar inside the same `hook_form_alter()`:

```
$form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#description'] = t('Enter your awesome title field details.');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Node title help text](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_help_text) module can be used to add help text to node title. Configuration is available to add description per content type

https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_help_text